# Creating a superset of Python dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have multiple raw data dictionaries that look like this:

```
raw_data1 = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15'],'SP':[35.6,56.7,41,41],'1M':[-7.8,56,56,-3.4],'3M':[24,-31,53,5]}
raw_data2 = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15'],'SP':[35.6,56.7,41,41],'1M':[-7.8,56,56,-3.4],'3M':[24,-31,53,5]}
raw_data3 = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15'],'SP':[35.6,56.7,41,41],'1M':[-7.8,56,56,-3.4],'3M':[24,-31,53,5]}
```

I would like to combine these in a top level dictionary such that the key for each element is raw_data1/raw_data2/raw_data3 etc. and the value is the individual dictionary itself. Any thoughts how I can create such a dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a new dictionary with those keys and use those dictionaries as the keys’ values:

```
top_dictionary = {
   'raw_data1': raw_data1,
   'raw_data2': raw_data2,
   'raw_data3': raw_data3
}
```